# could a 17-digit encrypts into a 15-digit by AES or other algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption

I use AES to encrypt a 17-digit number (for example, 12345678901234567),  then I Base64-encode the `byte[]` . The length of the final result string is 24. I want to barcode it, the 24 characters are too long. One string which consists of 15 characters would be good, and about 15-digits (for example 123456789012345 ) would be better.

Is there a way to my goal by any 
algorithm( AES, DES, 3DES ..)? And how?

My DES encrypt algorithm,

```
        public static  byte[] encrypt(byte[] datasource, String password) {            
            try{
                    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
                    DESKeySpec desKey = new DESKeySpec(password.getBytes());
                    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
                    SecretKey securekey = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKey);
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, securekey, random);
                    return cipher.doFinal(datasource);
            }catch(Throwable e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static void longToByteArray(long l, byte[] b) {
            b[7] = (byte) (l);
            l >>>= 8;
            b[6] = (byte) (l);
            l >>>= 8;
            b[5] = (byte) (l);
            l >>>= 8;
            b[4] = (byte) (l);
            l >>>= 8;
            b[3] = (byte) (l);
            l >>>= 8;
            b[2] = (byte) (l);
            l >>>= 8;
            b[1] = (byte) (l);
            l >>>= 8;
            b[0] = (byte) (l);
        }



        long aliveTime = Long.parseLong("13664547854160806");
        byte[] longAsBytes = new byte[8];
        longToByteArray(aliveTime, longAsBytes);
        byte[] result = DES.encrypt(longAsBytes, password);
        String en = REncrypt.base64Encode(result);
```

Comment: What is "17 digital"? And how should we know which encryption algorithm is right for you? You're not giving nearly enough information to help you!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I modify my question , hope this time i say it a little more clearer

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You can't get a quart out of a pint pot, and you can't put a quart into a pint pot either. Neither encryption nor any other technique is going to work here. You are going to have to reduce the size of your *input*, or else tolerate the possible collisions that arise if you *hash* it down to 15 digits.

Comment: @EJP 15 digit is impossible , what about 13 characters ? Please see Stephen C's solution. His approach  is wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An encryption algorithm will not compress data.  Indeed, if anything, the encrypted data will be harder to compress than the original.  The "scrambling" that the encryption algorithm performs will make any redundancy in the encrypted data harder (probably impossible) to extract.

A better approach would be to compress the 17 digit number *before* you encrypt it.  In this case, converting the decimal characters into a binary number will probably give better compression than a text compression algorithm.  A 17 digit number will fit into 8 bytes; i.e. a Java `long`.

So here's what I would do:

1. Convert the decimal digits to a `long`; i.e. parse it using `Long.parseLong` or similar.
2. Split the `long` into 8 bytes, and put them into a `byte[]`.
3. Encrypt the `byte[]`.  The result should be 8 bytes.
4. Base64 encode the bytes.

If you do it this way, your encrypted, base64 encoded number should be less than 15 characters.

Note: I'm assuming that you really mean encrypt; i.e. that you need to be able to decrypt and recover the original number.

**UPDATE**

This probably won't work with many / most decent encryption algorithms because they typically have a minimum block size that is too large.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_size_(cryptography).  If you read the article, you will get some insight into why that is so.

You should probably review what you are really trying to achieve here, and decide if encryption is the best way to achieve it.

Comment: the 3nd step result is 16 bytes.What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Ah ... you must be using a "block" based encryption scheme with a block size of 16 bytes.  Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_size_(cryptography)

Comment: +1 for the request for a requirements review. @Ron: Please try and clarify your goal/requirement _in the question_.